# Solve recurrence with symbols using SymPy: I got None

Tags: python, sympy, sage

I tried to solve a recurrence relation.

[image]

```tex
$$
\def\r #1{\langle r^{#1} \rangle}
0 = 8 n E \r{n - 1}
    + (n - 1)[n(n - 2) - 4l(l + 1)] \r{n - 3}
    + 4(2n - 1) \r{n - 2}
$$
```

This equation is from quantum mechanics. It derived from the Hamitonian with Coloumb potential.

[image]

```tex
$$
H = \frac{1}{2} p^2_r
    + \frac{l(l + 1)}{2 r^2}
    - \frac{1}{r}
$$
```

E and l are symbols, <r^n> is the expected value of r^n repect to the energy eigenstate.

I have a Sage script using SymPy to solve the recurrence relation. My goal is to express <r^n> as a function of E and l. Here is my script.

```py
import sympy
from sympy import Function, rsolve
from sympy.abc import n
l = sympy.symbols('l',integer=True)
energy = sympy.symbols('E')
r = Function('r')

f = 8 * n * energy * r(n - 1) \
    + 4 * (2 * n - 1) * r(n - 2) \
    + (n - 1) * (n * (n - 2) - 4 * l * (l + 1)) * r(n - 3)


print(rsolve(f, r(n), {r(0): 1}))
```

I don't know why the output result is `None`. I have tried to set `l` and `energy` to explicit interger, for example, 1. But it didn't help.

### Expected result

I am sorry. I don't know. The recurrence relation is too hard for my brain. I am not good at math.

### Output from print

There is no error, and below is the output.

```
None
```

### Extra question

If my recurrence relation doesn't have a general solution, is it possible to get the results of specific `r(n)`, for example `r(10)`?

### Reply for my extra question

I figured out the recursive method to generate the result of specific `r(n)`.

```py
from functools import cache
@cache
def expected_distance(n, l):
    if n <= -2:
        return 0
    if n == -1:
        return -2 * energy
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return  simplify((
        - 4 * (2 * (n + 1) - 1) * expected_distance(n - 1, l) \
        - n * ((n + 1) * (n - 1) - 4 * l * (l + 1)) * expected_distance(n - 2, l)
        ) / (8 * (n + 1) * energy))
```

Comment: Not every linear recurrence has a closed form solution.

Comment: If possible, can you also include the expected form of the solution? Also, the code runs with an error instead of returning `None`.

Comment: Updated. If my recurrence relation doesn't have a general solution, is it possible to get the results of specific r(n), for example, r(10)?